# Uso de técnicas de Inteligência Artificial para resolução de problemas complexos

Tags: algoritmo, inteligência-artificial

Diante da tarefa de desenvolver uma aplicação complexa, decidi fazer com que a cada vez que um ser humano interaja com o sistema, que este grave suas decisões, aplique pesos e nas próximas sugestões use de [heurística](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heur%C3%ADstica) com base em análises probabilísticas para aprimorar seus resultados e ficar cada vez mais próximo da perfeição para a situação de cada operador.

Após algumas pesquisas, vi que o que eu quero fazer já recebeu nome, [RBC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racioc%C3%ADnio_baseado_em_casos) e [Algoritmos Genéticos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_gen%C3%A9tico) e são técnicas de inteligência artificial.

Sei que terei de pesquisar muito e que provavelmente não há muito material sobre isso mesmo, mas seria de muita ajuda se alguém que já teve experiência desenvolvendo uma solução parecida, pudesse compartilhar e indicar o caminho das pedras, independente da linguagem utilizada.

Comment: Sua pergunta é ampla demais. Você deve começar decidindo qual algoritmo você quer (ou deve) usar. Depois disso, deve encontrar uma biblioteca na sua linguagem de escolha que implemente o tal algoritmo. No seu programa, sempre que os dados relevantes aparecerem, deve enviar essas informações para o módulo de IA.

Qualquer informação a mais do que isso depende da sua aplicação. Nâo tem como ser mais específico do que isso com sua pergunta sendo tão genérica.

Comment: Acho sua pergunta bacana, mas infelizmente tenho que concordar com o colega @Pablo. Ela está ampla demais, pois há inúmeros algoritmos que podem ser sugeridos. Além disso, não está claro o que o sistema faz automaticamente (isto é, onde entra a inteligência no sistema?): que tipo de dados você coleta e guarda do usuário? O que o sistema faz que precisa ser ajustado?

Comment: Não vou votar pra fechar porque você já ofereceu uma recompensa. Mas eu sugiro mesmo que você edite a questão pra tentar salvá-la adicionando detalhes (e, quem sabe, aproveitar o tempo restante da recompensa dada).

Comment: Este material tem muito conteúdo de inteligencia artificial e é voltado a tomada de decisões, ele explica vários aspectos e demostra isso em um software.
Isso deve te dar um rumo.
[A Inteligência Artificial no
Auxílio de Tomadas de
Decisão](http://www.gsigma.ufsc.br/~popov/aulas/icpg/20081/IA_na_Tomada_de_Decisao_Apresentacao.pdf)

Comment: Obrigado pelo Retorno de todos. Realmente a pergunta é ampla. Ela é propositalmente assim, pois eu procuro ver qualquer algoritmo de RBC e AG na prática. Independente da linguagem e aplicação. O objetivo da pergunta é obter o caminho das pedras para direcionar meu desenvolvimento, pois até agora, não encontrei nas minhas pesquisas nenhum algoritmo. Somente teoria.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boa tarde.
Como TCC, fiz um software de apoio a tomada de decisão para empresas que trabalham com manutenção técnica (seja ela de computadores ou não).
Meu método para a tomada de decisão do software foi o cálculo (com resultado em porcentagens) da reincidência de um fato. Por exemplo:

```
Notebook HP - Modelo Pavilion DV6000
Defeito: Não liga
Causas:
70% dos casos, problema de BGA
15% dos casos, pente de memória com defeito
10% dos casos, sistema operacional corrompido
5% dos casos, HD com defeito
```

Levei em conta as seguintes variáveis:
Tipo de Equipamento, modelo do equipamento e defeito apresentado.

A partir dessas informações modelei um banco de dados que pudesse armazenar uma base de conhecimento e que a cada nova ordem de serviço aberta, o motor de inferência auxiliaria na tomada de decisão.
A mesma estrutura eu repeti para a solução da causa da seguinte forma:

```
Notebook HP - Modelo Pavilion DV6000
Defeito: Não liga
Causa: Sistema operacional corrompido
Soluções:
60% dos casos, formatação
30% dos casos, recuperação do sistema
10% dos casos, recuperação do boot do sistema
```

Então, resumindo, o que eu fiz foi:
Para cada tipo e modelo de equipamento com o defeito X, poderá haver N causas e cada causa poderá haver N soluções
Caso seja necessário, posto o modelo do banco aqui.

Segue o modelo que eu vinha trabalhando pra atualizar:
Há mais uma tabela chamada Eventos, que tem a responsabilidade de armazenar quando ocorreu o evento, o que ajuda mais ainda a filtrar as probabilidades de causas e soluções do defeito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Espero ter ajudado!
Oss

> Curiosidade: desenvolvi em php(sem framework) e mysql. hehe

Comment: interessante, se puder compartilhar para dar uma olhada.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Isso já ajudou muito. É um exemplo prático de RBC.

Comment: O sistema que eu estou trabalhando fará quadro de horários para o BRT da minha cidade.

Quando o operador fizer uma alteração em um quadro sugerido o sistema deverá gravar essa alteração como um caso e para as próximas sugestões de quadro, deverá considerar esses casos para tomada de decisão.

Uma das minhas dificuldades era a de definir valores para a tomada de decisão e com a sua ajuda vi que tenho que tratar da seguinte forma: Cada interação é um caso, o caso existe para resolver um problema e cada problema tem N soluções possíveis.

Comment: O percentual de uma solução aplicada em relação à outra já é um bom valor para a heurística do algoritmo.

Meu próximo desafio é criar parâmetros no quadro de horários que possibilitem relacionar com os problemas na base de casos.

Comment: Muito interessante amigo, só vou comentar para que não confundam seu método com inteligência artificial, pois na pergunta o rapaz falou de inteligência artificial e o calculo de reincidência que fez não tem nada a haver ok?

Comment: Não concordo Giovanni. Pelo o que entendi isso é RBC. Você tem uma base de casos e a porcentagem da reincidência entra como um dos valores a se considerar para a tomada de decisão. O usuário está ensinando ao sistema conforme registra as resoluções. Não é essa a idéia?

Comment: A idéia do sistema é o aprendizado de ambos os lados. Imagina que a empresa contrata um técnico novo, nesse caso o sistema ensina o técnico. Porém em contra partida, é preciso que um especialista ensine o software primeiro. O aprendizado é mútuo e constante. Uma das técnicas de IA é justamente o sistema especialista que contém uma base de conhecimento (está destacada na imagem), já a técnica mais famosa da IA, que seria a RNA (rede neural de inteligência artificial), está implementada no cálculo de reincidências para apenas auxiliar a tomada de decisão e não tomar a decisão para o técnico.Oss

Answer (score 1):

Essa não é uma maneira adequada de se resolver o problema de quadro de horários.

Isso é uma questão matemática complexa e pessoas não irão fornecer boas respostas por mais espertas que sejam. Toda técnica de inteligência artificial parte de um treinamento, uma base de dados em que se tenham as melhores respostas para um conjunto de problemas, a partir daí o sistema aprende a inferir uma resposta nova próxima do ideal para um novo problema parecido. Bom não quero confundir mais, vou falar do que seu problema se trata.

Se trata de um problema de otimização e não de inteligência artificial.

Definindo com minhas palavras, toda vez que temos um recurso escasso que deve ser alocado, ou uma função que deve ser otimizada para um objetivo obedecendo-se restrições variadas, temos um problema de otimização.

O quadro de horários é um problema clássico de otimização, nele temos que alocar horários para o trabalho de pessoas, digamos 24h, mas temos diversas restrições, como por exemplo, temos funcionários trabalhando 8 horas, 6 horas, deve-se ter um intervalo de 1 hora entre as 8 horas, folga uma vez por semana, e diversas outras restrições legislativas.

Os algoritmos então procuram chegar a uma função otimizada cuja atenda todas as restrições impostas, minimizando-se ou maximizando-se o uso de recursos.

Outro exemplo seria no corte de madeira, quer-se maximizar o reaproveitamento da área útil e minimizar o custo. As restrições são os formatos de corte necessários e sua respectiva quantidade.

De fato o problema de horário, é explorado por algumas empresas que prestam consultoria ou apresentam algum software para facilitar a modelagem e resolução dos mesmos.

Um ex-professor meu na faculdade dá aulas de otimização, e tem uma empresa especializada em fazer escalas de trabalho utilizando essas técnicas que comentei, a empresa é http://escaladerevezamento.com.br

Inclusive possui um software no qual fiz um trabalho temporário, onde as pessoas montam os quadro de trabalho e suas restrições, e o sistema resolve a melhor escala possível atendendo a toda legislação, evitando multas e minimizando o número de funcionários, de fato economizando na folha de pagamento de empresas.

Eu tive aula desse negócio e acho mais difícil que inteligência artificial, tudo que tem que decorar alguma coisa eu acho mais difícil :-), não achei um material bom para te passar mas tem esse aqui www.maxwell.vrac.puc-rio.br/20533/20533_4.PDF que fala sobre o assunto, bom basicamente existe um algoritmo chamado min-max para resolver esses problemas, ele não tem um eficiência computacional alta da forma clássica, existem variações e métodos mais otimizados e complexos, estudados no mestrado, mas é um bom começo. Esse professor que falei foi aluno desse indivíduo alienígena aqui: 
Petr Iakovlevitch Ekel - http://www.pucminas.br/pos/eletrica/index-link.php?arquivo=docente&pagina=4124&id=262&PHPSESSID=893453e6e8b95dce0a3da4b3c1e3582a

Esse Petr dá aula de Métodos matemáticos no mestrado de engenharia elétrica da PUC e é simplesmente a maior autoridade mundial no assunto, o cara trabalha para governos, otimizando a instalação de malhas de energia elétrica em países, só para ter uma idéia...

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Giovanni. A parte inicial do software é justamente montar um quadro otimizado atendendo a especificações. Depois disso pretendo aplicar IA para que ele se torne cada vez mais assertivo, aprendendo com as interações. Portanto vou usar as duas coisas. Realmente há o risco de o usuário fazer besteira, más sempre vou solicitar um porque para cada interação que ele for guardar na base de casos, Portanto, se ensinarem besteira, ele vai fazer besteira mesmo. Já tinha lido um pouco sobre min-max, só não vi ainda como ele pode ser útil.

Comment: Continuo pensando que IA não cabe nesse problema e não deve ser usado, estamos falando de regras fixas jurídicas, o horário ótimo derivado da função não cabe aprendizado de máquina e sim otimização de sistemas. O que pode ser feito é tratar como um problema de satisfação de restrições e aplicar algoritmos de IA para limitar o espaço de busca, o que quase dá na mesma que a otimização, mas não vejo como as respostas do usuário podem contribuir para isso, só atrapalhar. São cálculos puros, se parar em cada interação de 1 bilhão de interações vai demorar mais tempo que a idade do universo :-)

Comment: Entendi seu ponto. Más minha aplicação não é de escala de horários (pessoal) e sim quadro de horários de ônibus. Montar um quadro desses vai muito além da legislação que por sinal não é muito restritiva. Tem que refletir os interesses da empresa e da população, portanto a interação de um ser humano com um bom senso crítico sempre será necessária. O que estou me propondo a fazer é dar formas para que a necessidade dessa interação seja cada vez menor. No primeiro instante haverá otimização com o uso de AG (usando o conceito de seleção natural). Depois pode haver interação e ai usarei RBC.

Comment: Ok, agora entendi, você vai montar os horários possíveis já otimizados, e depois coletar a percepção de usuários diversos e usar isso para sugerir horários melhores baseados no feedback, semelhante ao que lojas como a amazon fazem com seus produtos, então terá informações subjetivas que compõem um ranking de horários e vai oferecer isso a quem toma decisão, ou vai tentar tomar a decisão por IA. São dois problemas distintos. Você pode usar IA no segundo problema, ou pode usar de Business Inteligence também. Sua proposta é muito interessante, pessoalmente eu investigaria BI primeiro